# Adding two numbers of a bigger number in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java. I don't understand how to add two numbers together. Can anybody help me?

I.e:

1. number = 35 -> numbersum: 3 + 5 = 8
2. number = 39 -> numbersum: 3 + 9 = 12 -> 1 + 2 = 3

What is the code for this method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Show us some code you already tried, and someone will definitely help you out ;)

Comment: You should have did only one second search [Sum the digits of a given number](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-sum-the-digits-of-a-given-number)

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the concepts of numbers and decimal digits. Numbers denote a countable amount (which can be represented in many different ways - think of Roman numerals), and digits are elements of a specific way of writing down numbers (decimal representation, nowadays preferred by many humans). So, "35" does not universally consist of "3" and "5", but just happens to be written down like that by current-time, western-culture humans, which doesn't by itself apply to computers.

Answer (score 2):

```
int numbersum(int i) { 
   return i == 0 ? 0 : i % 10 + numbersum(i / 10);
}
```

Now this function is recursive; if you’re not sure what that means, I would strongly suggest learning the fundamentals of programming and computer science to help answer your own questions, yourself. Anyways best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some pseudo code to help you understand the algorithm behind your problem. Now it's up to you to implement it correctly in java.

While not being the fastest nor the shortest solution, it visualizes the steps in a very human readable way.

```
function digitSum(number) {
  // convert the int to a string, split it into its digits, map each digit back to an integer, sum all digits
  sum = number.toString().split("").map(digit -> digit.toInt()).sum()

  // if the sum has only one digit, return it
  if sum < 10
    return sum

  // if the sum has multiple digits, call the digitSum function again
  return digitSum(sum)
}

digitSum(35) // 8
```

This is the first way to solve your problem which came to my mind. As pointed out in the comments to your question, there are other ways to achieve the desired result.

It'd be best to look at some other ways and then choose the one you find the best.